# Javascript: TinyMCE + Highcharts

Tags: javascript, extjs, backbone.js, tinymce, highcharts

---

Please, give me some technical advice on how to implement the following in javascript.

I need to integate highcharts into tinyMCE in the following scenario:

- User chooses "Add chart" from tinyMCE menu,
- chooses chart (it's chartId is stored in variable),
- and the chart is rendered to tinyMCE's iframe (using backbone view, that is able to get chart info using chartId and render a chart, using its id, which is already implemented).

*Also note that all this is happening inside extJS application.*

This chart should be:

- sizeable and editable, e.g. like an image,
- but user is not able to put caret inside highchart and update text inside it, e.g. it's entirely selected like an image.
- when right-clicked, the tinyMCE's popup menu is shown, like for image, where i can set width-height-style etc.

I also need that when actual markup is received from tinyMCE, instead of the whole chart I would get a placeholder, e.g. tag "chart dataId="chartId""  or other format.

What is already done:

- I have attached tinyMCE to extJS and render it as a form.field
- I have added custom button to tinyMCE's toolbar
- I implemented rendering of chart into virtual , and then adding this div to tinyMCE's iframe dom, but the chart is rendered only partially and text inside chart is selectable, which is not accepted.

### Eventually, the main questions are:

- How to make chart render correctly into tinyMCE's iframe?
- How to make chart in tinyMCE selectable and editable in an image like mode?
- How to replace chart, when retrieving markup from tinyMCE, with some placeholder?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: backbone + extjs + highcharts + tinymce? sounds complicated! why don't you use extjs charts and htmleditor for this?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan extjs charts are to "heavy" -- 3+ charts on one page start to lag. HtmlEditor does not have tables, but we need them.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed some solutions for requirements like that. Here is the plugin that allows you to create/edit your own charts, it's free and has MIT license (charts as well), I using [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) there, it has a MIT license also.

How it works? Just puts SVG to your content or you can add some custom uploader - push file to your server and add IMG tag into your text.

Link: https://github.com/Axel186/charts-tinymce-plugin

Hope it will be useful, if someone have any questions, feel free to ask me.